# html table width not consistent

Tags: html, html-table

I'm having issues whereby my html table cell width are not consistent. I understand it's because of using colspan. Any way I can achieve to make the table cell consistent?

Sample jsbin:
http://jsbin.com/lozajiyeqi/edit?html,output

```
<tr>
     <td class="noborder" width="100"></td>
     <td nowrap="" bgcolor="#E5FADD" colspan="2" width="200" rowspan="1"> D1-09-08 </td>
     <td nowrap="" bgcolor="#E5FADD" colspan="2" width="200" rowspan="1"> D1-09-18 </td>
     <td nowrap="" bgcolor="#E5FADD" colspan="2" width="200" rowspan="1"> D1-09-28 </td>
     <td nowrap="" bgcolor="#E5FADD" colspan="2" width="200" rowspan="1"> D1-09-38 </td>
     <td nowrap="" bgcolor="#E5FADD" colspan="2" width="200" rowspan="1"> D1-09-68 </td>
     <td nowrap="" bgcolor="#E5FADD" colspan="2" width="200" rowspan="1"> D1-09-88 </td>
     <td nowrap="" bgcolor="#E5FADD" colspan="2" width="200" rowspan="1"> D1-09-98 </td>
     <td nowrap="" bgcolor="#E5FADD" colspan="2" width="200" rowspan="1"> D1-09-108 </td>
     <td nowrap="" bgcolor="#E5FADD" colspan="2" width="200" rowspan="1"> D1-09-118 </td>
     <td nowrap="" bgcolor="#E5FADD" colspan="2" width="200" rowspan="1"> D1-09-128 </td>
     <td nowrap="" bgcolor="#E5FADD" colspan="2" width="200" rowspan="1"> D1-09-138 </td>
     <td nowrap="" colspan="2" width="200" rowspan="1"> D1-09-168 </td>
     <td class="noborder" width="100"></td>
  </tr>
```

Suppose highligthed cell is also having the same width and colspan. But why they are having wider cell?

[image: HTML Table]

Comment: Don't use tables for layout - they should only be used for tabular data - which your data might be, but the table looks like it has been used for layout purposes (as you have empty cells at each end)

Comment: Try applying `display: inline-block;` to all of the `<td>`

Comment: Yes @Pete the output is for layout purpose. ZohirSalak, I've tried to add display: inline-block; it's able to fix my issue but how can i remain my text in center? After apply the inline-block, my text go up to the top of the cell